# CKQueryOperation resultLimit max and request count

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit, ckquery

What would be the max figure for `resultLimit`? I'm coming from parse.com so i'm used to using batch downloads that would comfortably pull 1000 rows of data at once when this would count as one request call. 
What kind of limitations are there in terms of `CKQueryOperation`?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKQueryOperation_class/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Maximum_Query_Results_Constants), you can use `CKQueryOperationMaximumResults`, however the docs do state:

> The actual maximum value is determined dynamically by the server based on various conditions.

And also:

> This constant is the default value assigned to the `resultsLimit` property.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yea with parse there seemed have been a definitive answer to these questions but i guess w ck its less definitive. Thank you sir

Comment: I think the ball park number is 100, yes just 100.

Comment: Does anyone have any experience trying to query and fetch for large data like 1k rows repeatedly?